# Autobahn - Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header error

Tags: node.js, autobahn

I am trying to build a WAMP server using NodeJS, wamp.io, and websocket.io.
Here is the server-side code :

```
var wsio = require('websocket.io');
var wamp = require('wamp.io');
var socketServer = wsio.listen(9000);
var wampServer = wamp.attach(socketServer);
```

And I am trying to test the pub-sub via browser using AutobahnJS. Here is the client-side code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Wamp Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="pages">
    <li>
      <button id="socket">Call</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min.jgz">
  </script>
  <script>
     AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = true;
  </script>
  <script>
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
       url: 'ws://localhost:9000/',
       realm: 'realm1'
    });

    console.log(connection);

    connection.onopen = function (session) {
      console.log(session);
     // session is an instance of autobahn.Session

    };

    connection.onclose = function(reason, detail){
      console.log(reason);
    }

    connection.open();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the connection always got this error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received
```

This part of code return 'unreachable'

```
connection.onclose = function(reason, detail){
    console.log(reason);
}
```

Is there any code I missed?

Comment: The handshake thing is a WAMP v2, your websocket server must be using WAMP v1. I had the same issue with Ratchet. See https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/issues/100